# regex for carriage return lines

Tags: regex

I am trying to write a regex for logs which seems to be working fine for log entries but in some log entries there are carriage returns which then fails to pick up the next line

```
([0-9]{2}\s[A-Za-z]{3}\s[0-9]{4}\s[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}(?:,[0-9]{3})?)\s?(.*)
```

above regex works fine for lines with no extra carriage return

```
01 Jan 2018 04:25:56,546 [TEXT] aabb33-ddee33-54321 (host-1-usa-east) this.is.sample.log: service is responding normal
02 Jan 2018 05:25:56,546 [TEXT] aabb33-ddee33-54321 (host-1-usa-east) this.is.sample.log: service is responding normal
```

but this fails to pick up `extra line 1` and `extra line 2` when on of the lines have added carriage return

```
01 Jan 2018 04:25:56,546 [TEXT] aabb33-ddee33-54321 (host-1-usa-east) this.is.sample.log: service is responding normal
02 Jan 2018 05:25:56,546 [TEXT] aabb33-ddee33-54321 (host-1-usa-east) this.is.sample.log: service is responding normal
extra line 1
extra line 2
03 Jan 2018 08:25:56,546 [TEXT] aabb33-ddee33-54321 (host-1-usa-east) this.is.sample.log: service is responding normal
```

I even tried to add ^ to match start but that only picks the first log entry

```
^([0-9]{2}\s[A-Za-z]{3}\s[0-9]{4}\s[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}(?:,[0-9]{3})?)\s?(.*)
```

Comment: What are you trying to capture? What's the string you're interested to match with your regex?

Answer (score 1):

You might use

```
(?<=\n|^)(\d{2} [A-Za-z]{3} \d{4} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}(?:,\d{3})?)\s?(.*?)(?=$|\n\d{2} [A-Za-z]{3} \d{4})
^^^^^^^^^                                                            ^ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The important part is the lookahead at the end for a date or the end of the string. Also make sure to lazy-repeat the `.`. The beginning also has lookbehind for a `\n` or `^` instead of the **m** flag so that the lookahead at the end for `$` will only match the end of the string, not just the end of a line.

https://regex101.com/r/YAkWBe/1

Also remember that you can simplify `[0-9]` to `\d`.

If you can't use the `s` flag (allows the dot to match a newline), then instead of repeating the dot to capture the (possibly multiline) string after the date, use `[\s\S]`, which will capture everything (all non-whitespace characters, *and* all whitespace characters -> everything):

```
([\s\S]*?)
```

Comment: It just dawned on me why your `\n` trick in the lookahead works.  It works because you are forcing a match to only occur if it's _not_ the last line; otherwise, the `$` might kick in for the last line.  I'll try to remember this! +1

Answer (score 0):

I can offer the following regex which works fine, except that it doesn't capture the very last log entry in your file:

```
([0-9]{2}\s[A-Za-z]{3}\s[0-9]{4}\s[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}(?:,[0-9]{3})?)\s?(.*?)(?=[0-9]{2}\s[A-Za-z]{3}\s[0-9]{4}\s[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}(?:,[0-9]{3}))
```

The long story short is that I added a lookahead to the end of your pattern, after the `(.*)`, which pauses when it encounters the start of the next log entry.  Then, the only other change is to use `(.*?)`, i.e. make the dot lazy so that it will pause at the lookahead.

Also, this regex should be run in dot all mode, where `.*` would match across lines.  If you don't have dot all mode explicitly available, you may be able to use `[\s\S]*` as an alternative.

### Demo

Comment: Don't forget the `/s` flag, which makes the `.` character also match new lines ;).

Comment: @npinti That depends on the tool/language the OP is using.

Comment: It is included in your link, and without it your solution doesn't work, unless I am missing something.